# Python set types to vectors without repetitions

Tags: python, list, vector, collections, python-itertools

I have k vectors and k types, where every vector is in the length n. n > k.

I need to put the types in the vector such that for every index, I should have a different type for each vector. the total number of types should equal between vectors".

For example, if types are

> ["H","M","L"] (k=3, n=6)

This is valid:

```
v1 = ["H", "H","M","M","L","L"] , v2 = ["L", "L","H","H","M","M"], v3 = ["M", "M","L","L","H","H"]
```

but this is invalid:

```
v1 = ["H", "H","M","M","L","L"] , v2 = ["L", "H","L","H","M","M"], v3 = ["M", "M","L","L","H","H"]
```

because

> v1[1] == v2[1]

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `n` is a multiple of `k`, this code will generate a list of vectors satisfying the constraints:

```
t = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
n = 8
k = len(t)
vectors = [[t[(j+i)%k] for j in range(0,n)] for i in range(0,k)]

for v in vectors:
    print(v)
```

When `n` is not a multiple of `k`, the problem does not have solutions. For example, with ["A","B"] (k=2, n=3), there is no way to create two vectors such that each index contains different types and that contains the same amount of each type. Here is all possible pairs of vectors satisfying the first constraint, however, none satisfies the second one:

```
AAA AAB ABA ABB BAA BAB BBA BBB
BBB BBA BAB BAA ABB ABA AAB AAA
```

I tried with other values of `k` and `n` and the same thing happens: We can achieve having different types at each index, but it is impossible to have the same amount of each type in each vector. The reason is that for a given index, the types are all different (and there is `k` types). But since all vectors need to contain the same amount of each types, all vectors must have a copy of all `k` elements somewhere. And if we decide to repeat one type, then we will have to repeat all types, and thus `n` will necessarily be a multiple of `k`.